# Use Class methods using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

So I think my design got messed little,
Here's what I got.

My application needs lots of enums, each contains multiple objects initialized and a "Get Best" method.

```
enum MyNumberEnum{
First("First", 1)
Third("Third", 3)

public String name;
public int num;

MyNumberEnum getBest(int num){
            MyNumberEnum bestNumber = First;
        for (MyNumberEnum number: MyNumberEnum.values()) {
            if (number.num <= num)
                bestNumber = number;
        }
        return bestNumber ;
}
}
```

All of the enums have the same getBest and all should have the field num,
Because Enums cannot extend, Thought maybe interface might help here but if an enum implements an interface then each of it's instances just implement not the enum itslef.

```
public abstract class Best {

public abstract Enum<?> getBest(int num);
}

class MyNumberClass extends Best {
    public abstract Enum<?> getBest(int num){return MyNumberEnum.getBest(num)}
}
```

So I thought maybe Create a Class and inside put the Enum, Then I could extend the get best method.

So To make it easy to use, I created a HashMap
And then added map.put("Number", MyNumberClass.class)

But then I got to a point which I got Class object, 
How can I use it's getBest method?

Thanks and sorry for my stupidness !

Comment: you mean you got the class instance or type?

Comment: @nullpointer 
I used 
map.put("Number", MyNumberClass.class)
So I get MyNumberClass.class I think it's the class type
edit:
The hashmap decleration HashMap<String,Class<? extends Best>>

Comment: This shall help you going https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html...try something and come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Your entire question is confusing. Do you want a class method (aka `static` method) or not? In your first code example, the method is not `static`, but then, what’s the problem with using an `interface`? In your second example, what’s the relevance of having a base class `Best` and a subclass? By the way, an `abstract` method can not have a body. And what is the relevance of the `HashMap` you are talking about at the end? Why do you map `"Number"` to `MyNumberClass.class`? Your question’s previous text did not mention a need to map from `"Number"` to anything; you were talking about `enum`s…

Answer (score 1):

Using the doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

I used:
            return (Enum)enumMap.get(enumName).getDeclaredMethod("getBest", Script.class).invoke(null, api);

Thought since it's inherits from Best class, and it's static method. 
it could use something easier like .getBest()
Apperantly it cannot.

Thanks 
@nullpointer